# GLM with autoregressive term to correct for serial correlation

Tags: r, model, statistics, correlation

I have a stationary time series to which I want to fit a linear model with an autoregressive term to correct for serial correlation, i.e. using the formula At = c1*Bt + c2*Ct + ut, where ut = r*ut-1 + et

(ut is an AR(1) term to correct for serial correlation in the error terms)

Does anyone know what to use in R to model this?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [GLMMarp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GLMMarp/index.html) package will fit these models. If you just want a linear model with Gaussian errors, you can do it with the `arima()` function where the covariates are specified via the `xreg` argument.

Comment: The package GLMMarp was removed from the CRAN repository. Do you know of any other package that would accomplish this?

Comment: All the packages I know about are listed at http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do this in R. Here are two examples using the ["Seatbelts" time series dataset in the datasets package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/UKDriverDeaths.html) that comes with R.

The `arima()` function comes in package:stats that is included with R. The function takes an argument of the form `order=c(p, d, q)` where you you can specify the order of the auto-regressive, integrated, and the moving average component. In your question, you suggest that you want to create a AR(1) model to correct for first-order autocorrelation in the errors and that's it. We can do that with the following command:

```r
arima(Seatbelts[,"drivers"], order=c(1,0,0),
      xreg=Seatbelts[,c("kms", "PetrolPrice", "law")])
```

The value for  order specifies that we want an AR(1) model. The xreg compontent should be a series of other Xs we want to add as part of a regression. The output looks a little bit like the output of `summary.lm()` turned on its side.

Another alternative process might be more familiar to the way you've fit regression models is to use `gls()` in the [nlme package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html). The following code turns the Seatbelt time series object into a dataframe and then extracts and adds a new column (*t*) that is just a counter in the sorted time series object:

```
Seatbelts.df <- data.frame(Seatbelts)
Seatbelts.df$t <- 1:(dim(Seatbelts.df)[1])
```

The two lines above are only getting the data in shape. Since the `arima()` function is designed for time series, it can read time series objects more easily. To fit the model with nlme you would then run:

```
library(nlme)
m <- gls(drivers ~ kms + PetrolPrice + law,
         data=Seatbelts.df,
         correlation=corARMA(p=1, q=0, form=~t))
summary(m)
```

The line that begins with "correlation" is the way you pass in the ARMA correlation structure to GLS. The results won't be exactly the same because `arima()` uses maximum likelihood to estimate models and `gls()` uses restricted maximum likelihood by default. If you add `method="ML"` to the call to `gls()` you will get identical estimates you got with the ARIMA function above.

Answer (score 2):

What is your link function?

The way you describe it sounds like a basic linear regression with autocorrelated errors.  In that case, one option is to use `lm` to get a consistent estimate of your coefficients and use [Newey-West HAC standard errors](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/sandwich/html/NeweyWest.html).

I'm not sure the best answer for GLM more generally.